# why is django altering my data after I import it?

Tags: python, sql, django, api

***UPDATED TO INCLUDE SAMPLES FROM SEED FILE***

I use an endpoint to clear and re-seed my data in my Django API.  The data is from two arrays of objects stored within my project and then imported to my views.py. One array is profiles and the other is posts, which which include integers to be used as foreign keys referencing profiles.  This works great the first time I run the functions after restarting the server.  However, when I run the function again, django somehow alters my imported data to swap the integer for the entire referenced database object it references. Obviously, this breaks my code.

**in views.py:**

```
from .fixtures.seed import all_profiles, all_posts

def seed(request):
    print('all posts zero: ', all_posts[0]['profile']) #logging the issue in question
    Profile.objects.all().delete()
    reset(Profile)
    for profile in all_profiles:
        add_profile(profile)
    Post.objects.all().delete()
    reset(Post)
    for post in all_posts:
        add_post(post)
    return HttpResponse('database cleared and seeded')

def add_profile(new_profile):
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.create(**new_profile)
    profile_instance.save()

def add_post(new_post):
    found_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=new_post['profile'])
    new_post['profile'] = found_profile
    post_instance = Post.objects.create(**new_post)
    post_instance.save()

def reset(table):
    sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(no_style(), [table])
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        for sql in sequence_sql:
            cursor.execute(sql)
```

**code samples from seed.py:**

```
all_profiles = [
  {
    "name": "Robert Fitzgerald Diggs",
    "profile_name": "RZA",
    "email": "abbotofthewu@wutang.com"
  },
...
]

all_posts = [
  {
    "title": "Bring da Ruckus",
    "body": "'Shaolin shadowboxing and the Wu-Tang sword style If what you say is true, The Shaolin and the Wu-Tang could be dangerous",
    "profile": 5
  },
...
]
```

**log when running seed function first time:**

```
all posts zero:  5
[04/Feb/2021 00:01:37] "GET /utility/seed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27
```

**log when running second time:**

```
all posts zero:  Corey Woods
Internal Server Error: /utility/seed/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Profile'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/main_app/views.py", line 79, in seed
    add_post(post)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/main_app/views.py", line 91, in add_post
    found_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=new_post['profile'])
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 418, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 76, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/Users/jedgodsey/Documents/Projects/fromtheslumsofJSON/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Profile: Corey Woods>.
[04/Feb/2021 00:01:43] "GET /utility/seed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 134068
```

What the heck is going on here? Is this some of that django "dark magic" I've been warned about? I've tried to set things up conditionally to get things to work, but haven't been successful so far.  I'm guessing django stores my imported data in memory somewhere rather than re-importing every time things are run, but I can't see anywhere I've instructed it to change that data regardless. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code to `all_posts` and `all_profiles` from `.fixtures.seed`?

Comment: @Foot Yes, thank you... Just updated with a couple of snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this yourself, there's no black magic involved.

```
    # Get a profile by ID using the `profile` key's value
    found_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=new_post['profile'])
    # Assign back to the same key (so it's now that model)
    new_post['profile'] = found_profile
```

Since you don't grab copies of the seed data or anything, this mutation will persist between requests. The first request would work, subsequent requests wouldn't.

You might want to do `new_post = new_post.copy()` within that function to do a shallow copy if you need to mutate the dict.

Comment: Boss! Thank you! So did this happen because the function is essentially holding state for as long as the server is up and taking the parameter from this rather than obtaining it again?

Comment: Yep, since it's just a variable from an imported module.